# How do i add element to array that is inside dictionary for set_fact variable

Tags: ansible

I've created a variable with set_fact which is a dictionary that contains two values of arrays. How do I push new elements to either array?

```
- set_fact:
    results: "{{ results | default({ 'corrections': [], 'errors': [] }) }}"

- name: update errors
  set_fact:
    results: "{{ results.errors }} + [some error found]"
```

also tried this and received error `unhashable type: 'list'"`

```
set_fact:
  results: "{{ results | combine({results.errors : results.errors  + ['some error'] }) }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not that easy to push new values into a dict. This is not directly provided for in this form.

`set_fact` is to define a variable, thereby the variable must be present completely defniert, it is not so trivial to change a value in the structure, as one is used to it from some programming languages. So you can not directly address a key and assign a new value.

---

Depending on the use case it can be easier to keep the result in two different variables (e.g. `errors` and `corrections`) and to merge them only at the end.

The filling of the list, exemplary for `errors`:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    errors: "{{ errors | default([]) + ['new error item'] }}"
```

1. `errors`: reads the existing list
2. `default([])`: in case `errors` is not defined yet, fallback to empty list
3. `+`: concatenation of two lists
4. `[...]`: list to be added

Creating the dict at the end:

```yaml
- name: build results dict
  set_fact:
    results:
      corrections:  "{{ corrections | default([]) }}"
      errors: "{{ errors | default([]) }}"
```

The result could look like this:

```
"results": {
    "corrections": [],
    "errors": [
        "new error item"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, this would also work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it with following solution.

```
set_fact:
  results: "{{ results | combine({'errors' : results.errors  + ['some error'] }) }}"
```